# How to debug lua code inside nginx config?

Tags: debugging, nginx, lua

I want to insert log points (io.write) inside my lua code which itself is in nginx configuration (using HttpLuaModule for nginx).
How to do that?
Access and error logs are not showing them.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

When running under nginx, you should use ngx.log. E.g:

`ngx.log(ngx.STDERR, 'your message here')`

For a working example, see http://linuxfiddle.net/f/77630edc-b851-487c-b2c8-aa6c9b858ebb

For documentation, see http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.log

Comment: Is there a way to change the log message format? Currently i'm getting a verr long messages, with date, host etc. 
.
"2017/03/03 05:31:22 [] 44#0: *17 [lua] content_by_lua(proj1.conf:110):3: your message here, client: 172.18.0.1, server:"

Answer (score 11):

Another option for Lua debugging in nginx (in addition to "printing") is to use a Lua IDE that supports remote debugging. I posted [instructions](http://notebook.kulchenko.com/zerobrane/debugging-openresty-nginx-lua-scripts-with-zerobrane-studio) on how this can be done with ZeroBrane Studio IDE. After you set it up, you get most of debugging functions you'd expect, like stepping, breakpoints, inspections of variables, stack traces, and a console to run Lua commands remotely.

Comment: thank you paul I will try this method . I prefer this way of working rather than printing values all the time.

Answer (score 3):

another troubleshooting tool for openresty is [lua-resty-console](https://github.com/nicoster/lua-resty-console), which allows you to check the lua variable, imported modules, call functions etc.
all you have to do is to install it use luarocks and insert a few lines into you nignx.conf. launch the client and here you go.

```
[9] ngx(content)> ngx.config.prefix()
=> /workspace/lua-resty-console/
[10] ngx(content)> ngx.config.ngx_lua_version
=> 10011
[11] ngx(content)> ngx.config.nginx_configure()
=>  --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/openresty/1.13.6.1/nginx --with-cc-opt='-O2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/pcre/include -I/usr/local/opt/openresty-openssl/include' --add-module=../ngx_devel_kit-0.3.0 --add-module=../echo-nginx-module-0.61 ...


[12] ngx(content)> ngx.sha →→
ngx.sha1_bin()  ngx.shared.     
[12] ngx(content)> ngx.shared. →→
ngx.shared.mycache.    ngx.shared.metrics.  
[12] ngx(content)> c = ngx.shared.mycache
=> nil
[13] ngx(content)> c
=> { <userdata 1>,
  <metatable> = <1>{
    __index = <table 1>,
    add = <function 1>,
    delete = <function 2>,
    flush_all = <function 3>,
    flush_expired = <function 4>,
    get = <function 5>,
    get_keys = <function 6>,
    get_stale = <function 7>,
    incr = <function 8>,
    llen = <function 9>,
    lpop = <function 10>,
    lpush = <function 11>,
    replace = <function 12>,
    rpop = <function 13>,
    rpush = <function 14>,
    safe_add = <function 15>,
    safe_set = <function 16>,
    set = <function 17>
  }
}
[14] ngx(content)> c:set('a', 1)
=> true
[15] ngx(content)> c:get('a')
=> 1
[16] ngx(content)> c:get_keys()
=> { "a" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to mikaraento's answer, make sure nginx logging is enabled in nginx.conf or override config file

```
error_log /dev/stdout info;
```